# Laravel, get data with polymorphic table not updating after delete

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to remove a record in my relation table and then fetch all records and return them with JSON to display the updated list. The problem is that when i am trying to get the data after delete it returns the data as if the record is not deleted but when i check the record is deleted.

This is how i'm deleting the record.

```
public function sellCat(Request $request)
{
  $cat = Cat::find($request->pivot['id']);
  $cat->delete();
  $user = Auth::user();

  // This returns the users cats as if the above was not deleted ??
  return $user->cats;
}

User-Model:
public function cats()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Cat::class, 'animals')->withPivot('id');
    }

Cat-Model:
    public function cats()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('App\User', 'animals');
    }
```

Animals model is empty but it's a relation table that takes user_id, animal_id animal_type.

Comment: Please put `dd(Auth::user()->relationLoaded('cats'));` before the `return` statement. What's the result?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir The result is a large script window.sfdump string in the data attribute.

Comment: Replace `dd(` with `var_dump(`.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir The result is now a bool(true) followed by an array of object containing the cats and their pivot that i had before the delete.

Comment: Somewhere, you must be calling `$user->cats`/`Auth::user()->cats` *before* you delete the cat.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Do you mean i should try that ( i did, did not work). And i am not calling anything before the delete besides only the user by doing $user->Auth::user();

Comment: No, this is what causes the issue. Is there a `$with` property in the `User` model?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Yes in the user model there is $with property for the cats yes.

Comment: If you would repeat your code line by line in `php artisan tinker` you will understand why this is going on. The answer of Jonas could be the solution to your issue. Anything loaded from your database becomes a resource. Deleting an entry will not delete it from the resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the `User::$with` property. When you load the user, you automatically load the `cats` relationship. That's why the cat is still there after you deleted it.

Remove the `$with` property or reload the relationship:

```
return $user->load('cats')->cats;
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfect. It makes sense since i am loading it with the user.